# Sum of all prime numbers

Tags: python-3.x

I want the sum of all prime numbers till 2 million. My program logic is correct but it takes too much time with 2 million. How can I make it faster?

```
num_l=[]
y = int(input("enter till what number do you want the sum"))
for count in range(0,y):
           num_l.append(count)

total = 0 

for counter in range(0,y):
           num = num_l[counter]
           if num > 1:  
              for i in range(2,num):  
                  if (num % i) == 0:   
                      break  
              else:
                         total = total + num
                         
print(total)
```

Comment: What is your time limit?

Comment: Like with this currently it makes more than an hour so ig 15-20 mins max?

Comment: Division checks for primality are slow.  Use a [sieve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes) instead.

Comment: you could download and use a list of known primes. why calculate them? is this a CS assignment?

Comment: @Kaii Its a Project Euler Question.

Answer (score 1):

just use a function to check that it is prime or not and if it is then add it to a counter (for total). The code below takes about 20 seconds to find what you want.
One more thing is that your algorithm for testing if a number is prime or not is having a long range of numbers to go through you don't need to test to the last number you just need to go through for a range of square root of the number.

```
import time


def is_prime(n):
    if n == 1:
        return False
    elif n == 2:
        return True
    else:
        for i in range(2, int(n**0.5)+1):  # this range is just enough
            if n % i == 0:
                return False
        return True


counter = 0
start = time.time()
for i in range(1, 2*10**6): # you can change this range for taking it as input
    if is_prime(i):
        counter += i
print(counter)
print(time.time() - start)
```

Comment: @ Kurosh I didn’t understand what you did on this line: `range(2, int(n**0.5)+1):`

Comment: I recommend reading this "https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/sieve-of-eratosthenes/" for the math behind it.

Comment: Why would the lists be a any time problem here, let alone a major one?

Comment: @superbrain I made a mistake, it's not the case at all.

Comment: @superbrain It is a problem because it takes very long to reach 2 million thus making it inefficient.

Comment: @Shloakr You said you want "15-20 mins max". The list stuff takes [less than 1 second](https://tio.run/##fY/BCsIwEETv@YqlpwRFil5E6JeUItFGG0g3Id1Q8vUxjUrrxbkszDxmWBdpsHg6O58ShvFqmrZjERrQSFyjC8QrhaQ8kDYG5kESZO6Wjd5CtAFmiQQ0KJjCWAnBHtbD3YZsagQv8al4vY/iwmBVWTpI5xT2vMCCMbIkTV6uga0leedvTeZLWfuhu23@bXzf3UJu418x55efCytSOtZFLw). You don't make sense.